# How to add Chromedriver to existing Docker?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, selenium-chromedriver

I've personal ASP.NET Core project which scrapes data from the web using Selenium and Chromium and saves it in local sqlite database.

I want to be able to run this app in Docker image on my Synology NAS. Managed to create and run Docker image (on my Mac), it displays data from sqlite db correctly, but getting error when trying to scrape:

```
The chromedriver file does not exist in the current directory or in a directory on the PATH environment variable.
```

From my very limited understanding of Dockers in general, I understand that I need to add chromiumdriver inside the docker somehow.

I've searched a lot, went trough ~30 different examples and still can't get this to work.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a new image based on the existing one, in which you add the `chromedriver` binary. In other words you need to extend your current image.

So create a directory containing a `Dockerfile` and [the `chromedriver` binary](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads).

Your `Dockerfile` should look like this:

```
FROM your_existing_image_name:version
COPY chromedriver desired_path_inside_container
```

Then open a terminal inside this directory and execute:

`docker build -t your_existing_image_name:version++ .`

After that you should be able to start a container from the newly created image.

Some notes:

- I have assumed that your existing image has been tagged with a version. If it is not the case then remove `:version` from `Dockerfile`
- Similarly, remove `:version++` from the build command. However, is a good practice to include versioning in your images.
- I have not add any entrypoint assuming that you do not need to change the existing one.

Comment: Thank you! This solved chromedriver not found issue, but now I'm getting error: "/app/chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libglib-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:52389/"